# JS Render interpreting hyphen in property name as subtraction sign

Tags: jsrender

I'm using JS Render to iterate over some data which uses hyphens in property names.

`{{:image_one.sizes.natural-massive}}`

That is returning a NAN result because it's attempting to run a mathematical operation. How can I force JS render to treat that as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use brackets as property accessor.

See the docs for path notation: [Using the 'bracket' property accessor: object["property"]](https://www.jsviews.com/#paths@bracketnotation)

In your case, you can write:

```
{{:image_one.sizes["natural-massive"]}}
```